# how do i return the Top Parent Array name of a nested Array?

Tags: powershell

Master Array has 6 Arrays in it.
I Look inside each of the 6 Arrays to search for a value.
When i find the Value i want to return the name of the Array it was found in?

```
#this is a basic extract to simplify what i am trying to get i am sure its 
#staring me in the face i just cannot work it out.

$Restaurants = @($PacRests, $CenRests, $MountRests, $HIRests, $ERests, 
$AtRests)
ForEach ($Restaurant in $Restaurants)
{ #this will return the entire contents of $Restuarant Array in a list
      Write-output $restaurant

ForEach ($R in $Restaurant)
    { #this will return the actual single value inside the 
$restaurant Array
Write-output $R
#What i need is the name of the Array the $R was found in.
#so $R.parentvalue but that does not work.
#so lets say $R is found inside $cenRests i need to identify that
}
}
```

Comment: you could make a custom object with a `.Name` & a `.Data` property - or perhaps make a hashtable of those items. that would let you use `$RestaurantList['PacRests']` to get the array from the hashtable OR use `$RestaurantList[$Index].Name to get the names from an array.

Comment: Lee this was perfect - using hashtables and all is working great. It's not letting me make your post the answer though?

Comment: kool! glad to know that you got it working ... [*grin*] ///// my comment is not in the answer box, so it can't be marked as such. it doesn't seem in-depth enuf to qualify as an "answer" ... and your thanks is all that i need.